# How to scan multiple Git commits to see if/when a specific bit of text was added to the codebase in the last month

Tags: ios, git, version-control

We have a monthly release schedule where we are adding commits to a given release throughout the month and then a release branch is cut and it ships to production.

At some point in the dev cycle of the last release it looks like a change was made and the app is crashing in production. The clue in the crash report is as follows:

```
-[NSOperationQueue isHidden]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

So this is basically saying we are calling isHidden on an object that doesn't respond to that message. This tells me "isHidden" is the culprit. An app-wide search for "isHidden" returns tons of results so I am wondering what approach would be the best for scanning the last release version (consisting of many commits) for any commits that added the text "isHidden" to the app.

Is this something I can do with Git alone, or is there a separate tool that would make this more feasible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git log -SisHidden
```

finds commits that add or remove instances of “isHidden”.  (Merely editing a line that contains the search string isn’t enough.)

Comment: Thank you! What if I wanted to search for the closing bracket as well? So "isHidden]"? I tried it and the results didn't appear to be accurate, not sure if I need to escape it or not.

Comment: @Lizza: Quoting is a matter for your shell; usually `]` by itself needs none.  The -S option treats its argument literally unless you use `--pickaxe-regex`.